# When Android phone has SoC with 6 cores then what does it mean form app developer perspective

Tags: android, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu-cores, android-thread

I have phone with [Snapdragon 632 Mobile Platform](https://www.qualcomm.com/snapdragon/smartphones/moto-g7-play) and some random Android app which shows what your phone has inside (RAM, SoC, sensors, screen density etc.) shows it has 8 cores.

**What does it mean from Android app developer perspective?**

So I can start (theoretically) up to 8 independent [processes](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Processes) which can do work in parallel? Or this has to do with [Java's Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)? Or none, find something else to study :) ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *...up to 8 independent processes which can do work in **parallel**?*

Well, **no**.
A process-based **true-`[PARALLEL]`** execution is way more complex, than a *just*-**`[CONCURRENT]`** orchestration of processes ( well known for every serious multitasking / multiprocessing O/S designer ).

> **Q** : *What does it mean **from** Android app **developer perspective?***

The SoC's 1.8 [GHz] 8-core CPU, reported by your system, is just a one class of resources the O/S has to coordinate all processes' work among - RAM being the next, storage, RTC-device(s), a (global) source of randomness, light-sensor, gyro-sensor(s), etc.

All this **sharing-of-resources** is a sign of a ***just***-`[CONCURRENT]` orchestration of processes, where opportunistic scheduling permits a Process to go forward, once some requested resource ( CPU-core, RAM, storage, ... ) gets free to use and scheduler permits a next one waiting to make a small part of it's work and releasing and returning all such resources back, once either a time-quota expires, a signal-request arrives or some async awaiting makes such process to have to wait for some external, independently timed event ( yes, operations across a network are typical case of this ) or was ordered to go and sleep (so, why to block others who need not wait ... and can work during that time or "sleep" ).

O/S may further restrict **processes**, to become able to use but some of the CPU-cores - this way, such planning may show up, that a physically 8-core CPU might get reported as but a 6-core CPU from some processes, while the other 2-cores were affinity-mapped so that no user-level process will ever touch 'em, so these remain, under any circumstances, free/ready to serve the background processes, not interfering with other, user-level processing bottlenecks, that may happen on the remaining, less restricted 6-cores, where both system-level and user-level processes may get scheduled for execution to take place there.

On a **processor level**, further details matter. Some CPU-s have SIMD-instructions, that can process many-data, if properly pre-aligned into SIMD-registers, in one and single CPU-instruction step. On the contrary, some 8+ core CPU-s have to share but 2 physical FMA-uop units that can multiply-add, spending but a pair of CPU-CLK-cycles. So if all 8+ cores ask for this very same uOP-instruction, well, ***"Houston, we have a small problem here ..."*** - CPU-design thus CISC-CPUs have introduced ( RISC-s have completely different philosophy to avoid getting into this ) a superscalar pipelining with out-of-order instruction re-ordering, so 2-FMA-s process each step but a pair of such pack of 8-requested FMA-uops, interleaving these, on a CPU-uops level, with other ( legally re-ordered instructions ) work. Here you can see, that a deeper **L**evel-**o**f-**D**etail can surprise during execution, so HPC and hard-RealTime system designers have to pay attention to even this LoD ordering, if System-under-Test has to prove it's ultimate robustness for field-deployment.

**Threads** are in principle way lighter, than a fully-fledged O/S Process, so way easier to put/release from CPU-core ( cf. a context-switching ), so these are typically used for in-process `[CONCURRENT]` code-execution ( threads typically share the O/S delivered quota of CPU-time-sharing - i.e. when many O/S Processes inside your O/S's scheduler's queue wait for their time to execute on shared-CPU (cores), all their respective threads wait either ( no sign of thread independence from it's mother Process ). A similar scheduling logic applies to cases, when an 8-core CPU ought execute 888-threads, spawned from a single O/S Process, all that among other 999-system-processes, all waiting in a scheduler queue for their turn ) Also the memory-management is way easier for threads, as they "share" the same address-space, inherited from their mother-Process and can freely access but that address-space, under a homogeneous memory-access policy (and restrictions - will not crash other O/S Processes, yet may devastate their own one's memory state... see Thread-safe-ness issues )

> **Q** : *...something else to study :) ?*

The best place to learn from masters is to dive into the O/S design practices - best engineering comes from Real-Time systems, yet it depends a lot on your level of endurance and experience, how easy or hard that will be for you to follow and learn from.

Non-blocking, independent processes can work in a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** fashion, given no resources' blocking appears and results are deterministic in `TimeDOMAIN` -- all start + all execute + all finish -- at the same time. Like an orchestra performing a piece from W.A.Mozart.

If a just-`[CONCURRENT]` orchestration were permitted for the same piece of music, the violins might start only after they were able to borrow some or all fiddlesticks from viola-players, who might have been waiting in the concert-hall basement, as there was yet not their turn to even get into the dressing-room, piano soloist was still blocked downtown, in the traffic jam and will not be able to finish her part of the Concerto Grosso in about next 3 hours, while bass-players have superfast fiddled all their notes, as nobody was in a need of their super-long fiddle-sticks and they are almost ready to leave the concert-hall and move to playing on another "party" in the neighbouring city, as their boss promised there...

Yes, this would be a *just*-**`[CONCURRENT]`** orchestration, where the resulting "*performance*" always depends on many ***local***-[ states, parameters ] and also heavily on ***externalities***-( availability of taxi, actual traffic jam and its dynamics, situations like some resource {under|over}-booking )

All that makes a *just*-`[CONCURRENT]` execution way simpler in execution ( no strict coordination of resources needed - a "best-effort" - a *"Do, if and when someone can"* typically suffice ), but in-deterministic in results' ordering.

Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart was definitely designing his pieces of art in a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** fashion of how to orchestrate its performance - this is why we all love Amadeus and no one will ever dream to let it be executed in a *just*-`[CONCURRENT]` manner :o)  <sub>no one will ever detect, the today's product of in-deterministically performed piece was the same as was performed, under different external set of external and other conditions, last night or last week, so no one could say if it was Mozart's piece or not at all ... God bless true-`[PARALLEL]` orchestration never permits to devastate such lovely pieces of art & performs the very way that every time the same result is (almost guaranteed to be) produced...</sub>